# SQL Server Service Broker Stored Procedure Change

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I am a complete novice when it comes to service broker. My question is how to modify a service broker stored procedure. The procedure is very long hence not pasting it.

Service broker is used between two databases both ends there are same target and event stored procedure the event stored procedure created xml and target reads it and inserts into table.

But when I modify the target stored procedure nothing happens, in an insert statement for testing purposes I hard coded a dummy value and updated the stored procedure successfully but dummy value gets ignored and it still reads from the xml.

I dont know if its to do with the queuing or there is more to it that I don't understand.

Any guidance will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try altering the queue so it understands that the procedure has changed:

```
ALTER QUEUE MyServiceBrokerQueue
    WITH ACTIVATION (PROCEDURE_NAME = name, other parameters ...) ;
```